# Identifying DateTime interval proximity, with previous intervals in mind

Tags: c#

I need to figure out a way to track if a task has been performed according to an established interval of time, and mark it as "overdue" if not performed.

An example is I need to service a truck every 6 months. I track when the last service was completed, and a service could happen some days (or weeks) before or after the scheduled time.

I haven't started on code for this, mainly due to needing to wrap my head around the logic.

The database stores an initial relative time for reference (DateTime), the interval type (could be Hours, Days, or Months), and the number to fulfill the interval.

An example would be:

- Initial: Jan 01, 2020
- Type: Months
- Count: 6

Which would mean that every 6 months after Jan 01, 2020, the task would need to be completed.

The idea being that if the service is completed, that truck would be marked as not needing service, but if the next service hasn't been completed, the truck would be marked likewise.

Comment: _I track when the last service was completed, and a service could happen some days (or weeks) before or after the scheduled time._ More detail needed: if a truck is serviced after 4 months, is it 6 months or 8 months until it needs servicing again? Assuming it's 6 months, you can query for trucks which have not been serviced for 5 months (need a service) or have not been serviced for more than 6 months (service overdue). Which part of the logic are you having trouble with?

Comment: If it's serviced after 4 months, someone will be getting fired, however (jokes aside), regardless of what the skew is, a truck is marked as ready for that service on an absolute schedule, not relative to when the service actually happened.

Comment: You need a better definition for the interval before a service that counts. You say it is marked as ready for service on an absolute schedule, but if it is June 1, 2020 and the last service was May 31, 2020, should it be marked ready for service? If not, it isn't an absolute schedule.

Comment: How do you record it when the service is performed? Is there another column for "last service date"? Or do you have a separate table that is a list of service visits?

Comment: I have a second table, to provide a history. Forgot to mention this!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the most recent service date (`LastServiced`) as a `DateTime` and store the `MaxServiceInterval` property as a `TimeSpan` type. This would allow you to have a calculated property `NextService` that would return the previous date plus the maximum allowed interval. You could also have an `IsOverdueForService` property that would tell you if the vehicle is overdue for servicing by comparing the next service date with the current date.

The reason for using last service date is that the next service date should be based on the most recent servicing, not the initial servicing.

```
public class ServiceSchedule
{
    public DateTime LastServiced { get; set; } = new DateTime(2019, 01, 01);
    public TimeSpan ServiceInterval { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromDays(180);
    public DateTime NextService => LastServiced.Add(ServiceInterval);
    public bool IsOverdueForService => DateTime.Today > NextService;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, however schedules might change in the future, meaning having to edit NextService/recalculating everything if that were to happen.

Comment: Not sure i understand the problem. If the schedule changes to something else, just set `ServiceInterval` to the new value. For example, the code above is set to 180 days (6 months). If that changes to 3 months, all you have to do is set `ServiceSchedule.ServiceInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);`. There's no additional calculation involved.

Comment: I had misread your code. My apologies. The difference is that I have a table that describes the schedule, and a table that describes the completion of that schedule, to provide a history. For some reason I had thought you were discussing the completion table (which I incidentally forgot to mention).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys! Very helpful.

What I ended up doing (to not tie myself to future schedules that might change on me), was add an additional column/field to my "completed" table, with a DateTime that identified the scheduled service's timestamp. Once this was done, I could calculate from that based on the requirements of the schedule if it was overdue.

Example:

- Schedule wants a service to happen January 1st.
- Maintenance happens on January 4th.
- Timestamp of the completed maintenance shows the 4th.
- Scheduled column shows the 1st.
- Calculations would look at Scheduled, and AddMonths(6) (or as defined by the schedule) and compare that to DateTime.Now.